# wpf show (gif )window when waiting on data from api

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I want to show a Window loading in a wpf app when waiting on data from a API. I treid with a thread but get still following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. occurred

Comment: If you search StackOverflow for that error message, you'll get a vast number of related question and answers.

Comment: always error to close the thread

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to reference something that was created in another threads context. You need to pass in whatever context the new thread needs, by value.